# PHP/HTML Add A remove button

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, row

I have the code below to retrieve rows from a database where the username column matches the base directory name:

```
$username =  basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE username='" . $username . "';");
$html .= "<ul><center><p>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop
  extract($row);
  $html .= "<li><span style=\"font-family: verdana;\"><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$link}</a></span> <span style=\"color:white;  font-family: verdana;\">- {$notes}</span></li>";
  }
$html .= "</ul></center></p>";
echo $html; //display results...
```

How would I add a remove button next to each html row that is displayed to delete that row from the table?

This is the part where it displays the link and text and I need a remove button after that:

```
 $html .= "<li><span style=\"font-family: verdana;\"><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$link}</a></span> <span style=\"color:white;  font-family: verdana;\">- {$notes}</span></li>";
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: that's easy. But, looking at your question list. There's a bunch of question waiting to get vote for answer. Can you clean that up first? Remember, this is community site.

Comment: Side note: You should not `echo` HTML. You can embed PHP into HTML.

Comment: Ok, will do can you give me an answer for this one?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that, when doing some *write* operation on the server-side *(like deleting something from DB)*, you should use `POST`, and not `GET` -- so, you should work with a form *(or an Ajax call)*, and not a simple link.

Comment: @silent I have marked them all now :) Please could someone get me some code for this question. Thanks :)

Comment: No offense, but given your history of similar 101 questions I'd suggest to take a few tutorials about HTML authoring and PHP and MySql programming first. So why not hop over to [sitepoint.com](http://articles.sitepoint.com/) and learn some basics.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a submit button linking to the same page like

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop
  extract($row);
  $html .= "<li><span style=\"font-family: verdana;\"><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$link}</a>  <form action=\"{$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]}\" method=\"post\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"{link}\" name=\"Delete\" />
    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete\" />
    </form></span> <span style=\"color:white;  font-family: verdana;\">- {$notes}</span></li>";
  }
```

Then in your page do something like

```
if (!empty($_POST["delete"])){
     $query = "DELETE FROM links where link = '{$_POST["Delete"]}'";
     mysql_query($query);
}
```

That's the basic idea of how I would do it

Comment: I need the button next to the link how would I do that?

Comment: Well, if you run a DELETE FROM query you will delete the whole row - meaning any row of (links, notes) that contains your specified link will be deleted.

Comment: What does the if (!empty mean? I don't understand that bit.

Comment: You can add that at the top of your page. The form will refresh the page when you click on one of the "delete" buttons. Then that statement will check if your $_POST["delete"] parameter is not empty. If it's not empty, it means the user just clicked a delete button, and that you have to run the DELETE FROM query. 
That if statement makes sure you don't run the query when you shouldn't

Comment: should that if (!empty($_POST["delete"])){ be Delete?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='deletepage.php?id=$someid'>X</a>";
```

create a page that with `_GET['id']` parameter;

And on that page i.e. `deletepage.php?id=15`

```
$sql = "DELETE table FROM table WHERE id = ".(int)$_GET['id']

mysql_query($sql);

header("location: previoudpage.php");
```

Comment: would that load a new page, I need it preferably to stay on the same page or create a popup window...

Comment: @Will Evans, the best solution will be ajax. Send request to remote page, if the success is returned, remove the content WITH dom