# PHP/HTML/MySQL Add A Delete Button

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/HTML Add A remove button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288922/php-html-add-a-remove-button)

How would I add a delete button to the code below so on each row after each link and notes there is an X and when that is clicked it deletes that link and notes from the database and refreshes the page? The code is below:

```
$username =  basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link, notes FROM links WHERE username='" . $username . "';");
$html .= "<ul><center><p>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { //loop
  extract($row);
$html .= "<li><span style=\"font-family: verdana;\"><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$link}</a></span> <span style=\"color:white;  font-family: verdana;\">- {$notes}</span></li>";
}
$html .= "</ul></center></p>";
```

The button code needs to be in this line: `$html .= "<li><span style=\"font-family: verdana;\"><a href=\"{$link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$link}</a></span> <span style=\"color:white;  font-family: verdana;\">- {$notes}</span></li>";`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this: http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641 tutorial.

Comment: It doesn't help with the form..